# asp.net handler mapping of ajax rest api

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

All this handlers thing is new to me. 
Mapping requests of static content and requests with certain extension works fine but I still have some problems/questions.

I have a web page and in this web page I execute ajax requests to some rest API in our server.
For example: "http://localhost:8182/test/firstExample?param=aaa"
I want to map all those requests to a certain handler.
We can assume that all requests start with: "http://localhost:8182/test"

1. Is there a way to do it?
2. A more general question - I was able to map requests with certain extensions (for example - *.css) or to map requests of files from a certain directory (by putting another web.config in this directory). Is it possible to map for example all requests that have the string "test" in the url? something like:

   path=" * test * "

   I wasn't able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring here can be achieved by httpmodule which is request based logic and not by httphandler . Httphandler  is a extension based logic and can be made to work on custom based extension.

Comment: httpmodules capture all requests, right? no way to set the path like in handlers? I tried to use httpmodule the problem is that I have ajax requests and for some reason the httpmodule doesn't capture those requests and I didn't find a solution.

Comment: httpmodule captures all requests. That's true. Handlers can't be used for directory based request. PLease refer this article for your code.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29573/Using-HttpModule-to-Handle-Ajax-Calls

Comment: The problem with the solution in the link you gave is that it requires changing our javascript code (we use jquery ajax) and we prefer not to do it...